# Why there is a Quot-scheme, not a Sub-scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, moduli-spaces, definitions, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety, and $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Grothendieck has proven that there is a scheme $\mathrm{Quot}_X(E)$ parametrizing arbitrary quotient sheaves of $E$. It is probably a well-known question, but I found nothing in Google:

$$\text{Why not a scheme $\mathrm{Sub}_X(E)$ parametrizing arbitrary subsheaves of $E$?}$$

Does such a scheme exist? If yes, is it purely a question of style, like Grothendieck's definition of the projectivization $\mathbb P(V)$ as the set of one-dimensional quotients of a vector space $V$? If not, is it because cokernels of sheaves require sheafification, while kernels coincide with kernels for pre-sheaves?

Moreover, if one considers a reflexive sheaf $E$ (that is the canonical morphism $E \to E^{**}$ is an isomorphism) and its reflexive subsheaves, then there is a Sub-scheme via dualizing and taking a Quot-scheme. Is there a less restrictive constraint?

Comment: I think that this is a good question for mathoverflow. By the way, quot schemes parametrize *locally free* quotients. I guess that the answer is then that there are more locally free quotients than locally free subobjects.

Comment: @HeinrichD, I believe that Quot-schemes parametrize all quotients: if $E=\mathcal O_X$ and one considers a component with Hilbert polynomial of degree zero, it is isomorphic to Hilbert scheme of points. In particular, all such sheaves have zero-dimensional support.

Comment: Quick random guess: if you are parametrising subsheaves $F$ of $E$ up to isomorphism then this will be very badly-behaved, e.g. all rank 1 subsheaves of a free rank 2 coherent sheaf over a point are isomorphic, and there are many such isomorphisms, so no way is this representable (by a scheme, at least; it would have negative dimension, for example). If however you say two subsheaves are "the same" iff they're the same subsheaf, then you may as well use the quot sheaf!

Comment: @evgeny: The quotients in the Quot-scheme should be finitely presented and flat over the base, so in the special case that you are over the base these are just the locally free quotients. Maybe I'm wrong, but this is what the definition (for example in the stacks project) tells me.

Comment: @HeinrichD, if $X$ is Noetherian, then "a quasi-coherent sheaf of finite presentation" means "coherent"; if $X$ is projective, every coherent sheaf has proper support; and the condition that $\mathcal Q$ on $X \times T$ is flat over $T$ means that its nice as a family on $T$, but each member on $X \times {pt}$ may be arbitrary coherent sheaf, I believe.

Comment: For standard universal properties, you need the scheme to behave well under base change, which in these cases would mean tensor products. Tensor product is right exact, so a quotient remain a quotient, not left exact, so a sub may not remain a sub.

Comment: I'd say it is like the definition of $P^n$, but it is not purely a `matter of style'. This essentially rephrases Mohan's comment, but here it is: On the level of points, there is of course no difference between subs and quotients: we can just think of short exact sequences $0\to A\to E\to B\to 0$. Now as you consider families (say, over $S$), you really want sequences $$0\to A\to E\boxtimes O_S\to B\to 0$$ with $A$ and $B$ flat over $S$ (so you have a family of short exact sequences). But flatness of $B$ implies flatness of $A$, so we can forget $A$ and think of $B$ only.

Comment: A fundamental sense in which Grothendieck's definition of $\mathbf{P}(V)$ is not a "convention" is that it gives a meaningful notion of $\mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}) := {\rm{Proj}}({\rm{Sym}}(\mathscr{E}))$ in the relative situation over a scheme $S$ when the quasi-coherent $O_S$-module $\mathscr{E}$ is not locally free of finite rank (so passing to its dual is not a real option, and so "only one" option is available, namely Grothendieck's).  Also, if you read the *proof* of existence of Quot-schemes you'll see exactly how quotients are better-suited than subsheaves (related to Mohan's comment).

Comment: @Mohan, thank you! Could you make an answer from your comment, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For standard universal properties, you need the scheme to behave well under base change, which in these cases would mean tensor products. Tensor product is right exact, so a quotient remain a quotient, not left exact, so a sub may not remain a sub.